# Начало координат в sfml

Tags: координаты

У меня есть графическое отображение сигнала с помощью sfml. Но беда в том что в дальнейшем для определения центральных частот сигналов базовая конфигурация координат не подходит ибо максимум в числовом формате является самой нижней точкой на графике. В связи с этим у меня вопрос есть ли возможность переместить x0 y0  в нижний левый угол вместо верхнего левого?

Comment: А каким образом система координат, используемая *для отображения* мешает определять что-то там? Храните о обрабатывайте в одной системе координат, отображайте в другой - никаких проблем.

Answer (score 1):

Преобразуйте Y-координату для вывода по простой формуле с использованием высоты картинки

```
ynew = window_height - y
```